# How to reset the row index of dataset

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I'm a newbie to the whole Data thing... And I'm trying to clean my data and get them down to a form with which they can work.

`df = pd.read_excel('https://query.data.world/s/s3t37yqxxeoabyocyh6g33fojskwvq')`

`df.head()`
[image]

What should I do to re-store the index 2 row to 0th row?
(I want to delete the first three row
Survey Year, Timestamp Salary USD... these values are features)...... HELP!!!

Comment: Use `df = pd.read_excel('https://query.data.world/s/s3t37yqxxeoabyocyh6g33fojskwvq', skiprows=2)`

Comment: Use the skiprows option https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: You guys are the best, thank you! I did skiprows=3 and it worked out perfectly <3